# Label Studio: Can't sync png-files from subfolders in s3 bucket as tasks for project

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, label-studio

I run a label studio on an ec2 instance, and connected an s3 bucket with png-files organized in (many) subfolders:
(label_bucket/xxxxxx/13.png)

(label_bucket/yyyyyy/23.png)

...

Under settings/Cloud Storage/Source Cloud Storage/Edit you can specify the s3 bucket with credentials (is working).
You can set Bucket Prefix (label_bucket/)
You are able to set a File Filter Regex (I tried: .*.png$ and *.png)

Always got "Synced 0 task(s)" in return.

I suggest that this is a highly common task, to upload images as as label task, that are organized in a s3 bucket in such a way, and that the File Filter Regex field is just for this case.

Did someone solved this case before in their respective label studio project and can tell what I got wrong about the File Filter Regex field?

Is this feasible at all, or do I have to do this with a script and the label studio sdk package?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?